# Copy files from one path to another except .zip files

Tags: shell-script, cp

I need to copy all files from one UNIX path to another within the same server. However, there are some .zip files I want to exclude while copying. How can I achieve this using the [cp](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/cp/) command options?

Comment: are you copying recursively (`-r`)?

Comment: What shell are you using?  I have a feeling zsh would be able to do this easier than some others.

Comment: Please clarify: 1) Is this on a UNIX system, or a Linux system? 2) Which OS are you using? 3) Which shell are you using? 4) Do you wish to copy files which are in subdirectories of the source, or just the source directory? 5) Since the _cp_ command itself cannot do this alone, is it satisfactory to you other common shell commands? Please do NOT click Add Comment to respond; instead, click [edit] and clarify your question to provide this very useful information. Why? Comments accumulate. When new comments arrive, old comments can get pushed off screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it with just `cp`/globbing but using `find`/exec:

```
find /first/path/ -type f -not -name '*.zip' -exec cp {} /second/path/ \;
```

In order to avoid recursion you can add the `maxdepth` option:

```
find /first/path/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name '*.zip' -exec cp {} /second/path/ \;
```

---

Alternatively you could copy everything from the source to the destination and then go through and remove all the .zip files afterward:

```
cp -R /first/path/ /second/path/ && find /second/path -type f -name '*.zip' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Thank You Jesse, This is helpful !

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to move the .zip files out of the way with [mkdir](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osf1/2/mkdir/) and [mv](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osf1/2/mv), copy the remainder with [cp](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/cp/), then restore the .zip files to their original location with mv and [rmdir](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osf1/2/rmdir).

```
cd SOURCE && mkdir ~/dELETEmE && mv *.zip ~/dELETEmE && cp * DESTINATION  
cd ~/dELETEmE && mv * SOURCE && cd .. && rmdir dELETEmE
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if its necessary using only `cp`, but if using bash and being sure your files doesn't have spaces in their names, maybe like this?

Inside of your source path

`cp $(ls | grep -v *.zip) /destination/path`